# Getting current path in Windows form application not working properly

Tags: c#, path, localdb

I'm working on an app linked to a local db and I'd like to get the path of db d**y**namically. I don't know where exactly users will copy this app, so I'd like to get the path to the db automatically. I wrote the following code, it gets the path, but not exactly. I mean, if I have my app in: `C:\Users\ROG\Desktop` , it says that there is no db in `C:\Users\ROG` . So it doesn't get the last location of it. Why is that and how to solve it?

I connect to it as follow:

```
var connString = (@"Data Source=" + 
                  Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName + 
                  @"\Angajati.sdf");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use the following code

```
var connString = (@"Data Source=" + 
                  System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
                         System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),
                  "Angajati.sdf"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the following code to determine appllication base directory:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

Full code will look like the following:

```
var connString = "Data Source=" + 
              System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Angajati.sdf");
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using get current directory I suggest using Application Path. That's because if an `OpenFileDialog` be used the current directory changes but the applicationPath is the same.

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

I hope it would be helpful.

Comment: @MickyDuncan Thanks buddy.